# How do you configure a Django ImageField with upload_to and MEDIA_ROOT on Webfaction?

Tags: django, file-upload

I have the following model field in a django project:

```
headshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='/tmp', blank=True, null=True)
```

#### settings.py

```
# format                                    <project>/<app>
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/username/webapps/django/myproject/books/media/'
```

I have created a directory: `/home/username/webapps/django/myproject/books/media/tmp` and gave it `chmod 777` permissions.

I get the following error when I try to add a new image:

```
SuspiciousOperation at /admin/books/author/add/
Attempted access to '/tmp/Comment.png' denied.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://username.webfactional.com/app/admin/books/author/add/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: SuspiciousOperation
Exception Value:    
Attempted access to '/tmp/Comment.png' denied.
Exception Location: /home/username/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/core/files/storage.py in path, line 234
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Do I need `.htaccess` or some other settings to be able to write to this directory or is there something wrong with my Django config?

I would still like to know what `chmod` values to use and how to set `MEDIA_URL`. I'm thinking I might need to do something in `urls.py` for `MEDIA_URL`.

My project is set up on the webhost Webfaction if that makes a difference.

Comment: Also what would I set my MEDIA_URL to for the above if the webfaction panel application sub domain is say /blog. Would it be

Comment: MEDIA_URL = 'http://username.webfactional.com/blog/myproject/books/media/'

Comment: Fixed it. Seems like the answer was to use upload_to='tmp' instead of upload_to='/tmp'. Would still like to know what chmod values to use and how to set MEDIA_URL. I'm thinking I might need to do something in urls.py for MEDIA_URL. Not sure how to though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed it. Seems like the answer was to use upload_to='tmp' instead of upload_to='/tmp'.

Comment: This is correct. `upload_to` needs a *relative* path, but a path that starts with a `'/'` is an *absolute* path.

Answer (score 2):

I see you've marked this as answered, but still have some questions in your answer. Here is how I have this set up, in case you are still working on it.

---

Set up a new app for media (via the webfaction control panel). I used the "static_only" application because it should prevent users from uploading scripts and running them. You could also use one of the "static/cgi/php". Creating a new app for this (instead of using Django and making a new view) is good practice because it will have a lower resource overheard. Django is overkill for serving static files (images, css files, javascript files, etc.).

Bind your new media (static_only, or whatever you used) app to some URL, again using the webfaction control panel. I bound mine to media..com. `MEDIA_URL` should be set to the URL you can access your media through, and `MEDIA_ROOT` should be the root directory for the media app. Thus, in my settings.py file I have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/<username>/webapps/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://media.<mydomain>.com/'
```

It's best to do the same thing for `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL`.

As far as permissions go, the defaults should be OK - if you have troubles with that just ask.