# mapping django models.ImageField into an SQL table

Tags: sql, django, django-models, sql-types

i have an image filed in my model and i want to write SQL create table queries myself
my model filed is this:

```
pic = models.ImageField(u"initial_picture",blank=True,upload_to="/face")
```

and i wanna use command `CREATE TABLE SOME_TABLE_NAME` to create my table
but i don't know what should i use for the field type
i'v read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416881/insert-picture-into-sql-server-2005-image-field-using-only-sql) that i can use something like this:

```
Photo varbinary(max) not null
```

but i don't know if it's compatible for django and if it's appropriate for my model
i also have used `pic IMAGE DEFAULT NULL` like what i saw [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/103960-save-and-retrieve-images-with-sql-server/) and the result was a varchar(100) field in the database structure

any help will be appriciated
;-)

i'v tried both `Photo varbinary(max) not null` and `Photo varchar(max) not null`
the field is showing but when i press save, i get the following error:

`Attempted access to '\face\sample.gif' denied.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you keep the images in the file system, as plain files? This would be the corresponding SQL

```
`pic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```

for your pic field.

```
pic = models.ImageField(u"initial_picture",blank=True,upload_to="/face")
```

In the database, the `pic` field would only contain the path for the actual image file.

Comment: Django's ImageField, keeps the actual binary on the filesystem anyway. I have no idea what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: i have also found the answer for the error `Attempted access to '\face\sample.gif' denied.`
the answer was in this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869549/how-do-you-configure-a-django-imagefield-with-upload-to-and-media-root-on-webfac